# May I dynamically translate a piece of a string coming from a JSON file?

Tags: jquery, json, translation

I used the [jquery-lang-js](https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js) plugin to translate some elements of my webpage dynamically and it works. More specifically, I might translate every element contained in my HTML file.

I wrote a callback function to show results from a JSON file when required:

```
               for (let i = 0; i < lowCostHotels.LOW_COST.length; i++) {
                var entry = lowCostHotels.LOW_COST[i];                    
                if (entry.city == inputCity) {    
                    $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + entry.name() </td></tr>");
                }
            }
        }       
    });
};
```

An example of the result shown is:

> Leg 22 - Passo della Cisa - Pontremoli

which corresponds to the first `<td>`.

I want to substitute

> "Leg"

with

> "Etape"

That's to say, I want to translate a single part of a string contained in the JSON file:

```
{
  "legs": [
    {
      "name": "Leg 22 - Passo della Cisa - Pontremoli",
      "state": "Italy",
      "region": "Tuscany",
      "city": "Groppoli (Mulazzo)"
    },
    {
      "name": "Leg 22 - Passo della Cisa - Pontremoli",
      "state": "Italy",
      "region": "Tuscany",
      "city": "Groppodalosio"
    }
     ]
}
```

And I want to do that for every one of the 50 `<tr>`.

Is there any trick to do that easily or am I supposed to write a different JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, instead of a for you should use a forEach. Always use helper functions provided natively by js objects such as Arrays and strings. They are faster, shorter to read and and take less time to write. As a bonus, look into arrow functions as well if you're using ES6.

```
   for (let i = 0; i < lowCostHotels.LOW_COST.length; i++) {
      var entry = lowCostHotels.LOW_COST[i];                    
      if (entry.city == inputCity) {    
          $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + entry.name() </td></tr>");
      }
    }
```

Becomes:

```
lowCostHotels.LOW_COST.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (entry.city == inputCity) {    
    $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + entry.name() </td></tr>");
  }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Then if you only want to replace Leg with Etape:

```
lowCostHotels.LOW_COST.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (entry.city == inputCity) {    
    $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + entry.name().replace("Leg", "Etape") </td></tr>");
  }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

But you're pretty much manually translating/changing your JSON here. I'd recommend you look into a different translation method if the one you're using isn't translating everything correctly. On the other hand, if you only need a quick fix for a few missed words, then just a replace() will do the trick.